# ubuntu graphics issue (symbols get big and desktop cuts screen)

Tags: boot, 22.04, nvidia-geforce, vga

i have a problem.  I use Ubuntu 22.04 as the only operating system on my computer.  but i found a problem where my ubuntu symbol is very big and my desktop screen is crossing the border of my monitor.  (This is like the VGA not detected problem if it's on a Windows OS).  does anyone know how to solve this problem.  i need help.  Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried using the hardware controls on the monitor?

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu. Can you share some additional details like a picture or properly specify what you meant by Ubuntu symbol crossing border of the monitor? Are you able to log in to the desktop?

Comment: yes i can login to my desktop, but my ubuntu desktop UI is too big so it gets cropped by my monitor size.  The size of the UI display is not normal (too big) so it doesn't follow the size of my monitor so the UI display is truncated